# Can't get CJKAnalyzer/Tokenizer to recognise japanese text

Tags: c#, unicode, localization, lucene.net

i'm working with Lucene.NET and it's great. then worked on how to get it to search asian languages. as such, i moved from the StandardAnalyzer to the CJKAnalyzer.

this works fine for korean (although StandardAnalyzer worked ok for korean!), and chinese (which did not), but i still cannot get the program to recognise japanese text.

just as a very small example, i write a tiny database (using the CJKAnalyzer) with a few words in it, then try and read from the database:

```
public void Write(string text, AnalyzerType type)
        {
            Document document = new Document();

            document.Add(new Field(
                "text",
                text,
                Field.Store.YES,
                Field.Index.ANALYZED));

            IndexWriter correct = this.chineseWriter;
            correct.AddDocument(document);            
        }
```

that's for the writing. and for the reading:

```
public Document[] ReadMultipleFields(string text, int maxResults, AnalyzerType type)
        {
            Analyzer analyzer = this.chineseAnalyzer;

            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "text", analyzer);
            var query = parser.Parse(text);                        

            // Get the fields.
            TopFieldCollector collector = TopFieldCollector.create(
                new Sort(),
                maxResults,
                false,
                true,
                true,
                false);

            // Then use the searcher.            
            this.searcher.Search(
                query,
                null,
                collector);

            // Holds the results
            List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();

            // Get the top documents.
            foreach (var scoreDoc in collector.TopDocs().scoreDocs)
            {
                var doc = this.searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc);
                documents.Add(doc);
            }

            // Send the list of docs back.
            return documents.ToArray();
        }
```

whereby chineseWriter is just an IndexWriter with the CJKAnalyzer passed in, and chineseAnalyzer is just the CJKAnalyzer.

any advice on why japanese isn't working? the input i send seems fair:

プーケット

is what i will store, but cannot read it. :(

EDIT: I was wrong... Chinese doesn't really work either: it the search term is longer than 2 characters, it stops working. Same as Japanese.

EDIT PART 2: **I've now seen that the problem is using the prefix search.** If I search for the first 2 characters and use an asterisk, then it works. As soon as I go over 2, then it stops to work. i guess this is because of the way the word is tokenized? If I search for the full term, then it does find it. Is there anyway to use prefix search in Lucene.NET for CJK? プ* will work, but プーケ* will find nothing.

Comment: which versions of Lucene.Net/Lucene.Net Contrib are you using. I just tested using the latest version of the package available on NuGet and it works fine with your input

Comment: @Jf Beaulac - using 2.9.

Comment: I can answer one of your question : `プーケット` is Phuket, a city of Thailand. :) But I cannot answer the other.

Comment: Small comment on why Korean is working: It works because Korean, unlike Chinese and Japanese, uses space characters between words. However it does not use it very consistently, e.g. there can be long compound nouns or compound noun phrases with no spaces in them. For those you should still use a special tokenizer for Korean.

Answer (score 0):

I use StandardTokenizer. Atleast for Japanese and Korean text it is able to tokenize the words which contains 3 character or 4. But only worry is for Chinese character. It does tokenize the Chinese language but 1 character at a time.